# Get idxmax or idxmin of tuple-valued column in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a tuple-valued score that I'd like to get the row corresponding to the maximum value of. A toy example of what I'd like to do would be:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
                   'score': [(1,1,1), (1,1,2), (0, 0, 100), (8,8,8)], 
                   'numeric_score': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'value':['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']})
# Works, gives correct result:
correct_df = df.loc[df.groupby('id')['numeric_score'].idxmax(), :]
# Fails with a TypeError
goal_df = df.loc[df.groupby('id')['score'].idxmax(), :]
```

`correct_df` has the result I'd like in `goal_df`. This throws a bunch of errors, the core of which seems to be:

`TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype`

A working, but ugly solution is:

```
best_scores = df.groupby('id')['score'].max().reset_index()[['id', 'score']]
goal_df = (pd.merge(df, best_scores, on=['id', 'score'])
           .groupby(['id'])
           .first()
           .reset_index())
```

Is there a slick version of this?

Comment: What is your desired outcome? You say you want the maximum value, but can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks @GoodLuckGanesh, I updated the question to demonstrate what I'm driving towards.

Comment: If your scores were `(8,8,8)` and `(100, 0, 0)`, would you want 100?

Comment: Correct. I want the same behavior for ordering as in standard python (e.g. (100,0,0) > (8,8,8))

Comment: But standard ordering would miss `(0,0,100)`, but you would still want this tuple, correct?

Comment: I want the row where the tuple score is maximized according to the standard python ordering, so `(9, 0, 0) > (8,8,8) > (0,0,100)`.

Comment: I have left an answer below. If this does not get at what you are looking for, please elaborate further.

Comment: If it is critical to use `.groupby()`, I would encourage you to provide an example of why you need it, since it seems to me that my answer gives you the desired result.

Comment: If my answer works, please accept it and update your question to provide more insight (the explicit question about .argmax()), which will make it more searchable in the future.

Comment: Why won't `goal_df = pd.merge(x, best_scores, on=['id', 'score'])` be enough? In the example you've posted, you don't need to us `.groupby()` to get the desired result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188368/discussion-between-michael-k-and-goodluckganesh).

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question to be:

"NumPy's `.argmax()` does not work for tuples. For a Series of tuples, how do I determine the index for the maximum valued tuple?"

IIUC, this will return the desired outcome:

```
df.loc[df.score == df.score.max()]
```

Comment: This works in the case of a global max; this needs to be done on a group-by-group basis.

Comment: Do you need the data in corresponding columns? If not, `df.groupby('id').score.max()` will get you the max by group